# How can I remove Skype phone number recognition?

Tags: php, javascript, html

If Skype is installed, phone numbers are showing up with a Skype icon in some browsers.

I don't want to show Skype icons anywhere, ever.

Is there any JavaScript or PHP function that can handle this?

Comment: Perhaps consider changing the accepted answer to krisdyson's rather than Jigar's (which has negative votes). Note that hans' answer is fragile to future changes and doesn't prevent DOM changes.

Answer (score 23):

Use the following CSS to prevent skype from formatting the numbers on your page:

```
span.skype_pnh_container {display:none !important;}
span.skype_pnh_print_container {display:inline !important;}
```

**edit** 
Skype starts adding numbers in the class names to make them unique. You can solve by using the new Css selectors

```
span.skype_pnh_container {display:none !important;}
span.skype_pnh_print_container, span[class^="skype_pnh_print_container"] {display:inline !important;}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for me.  This should be the real correct answer.

Comment: tl;dr: this answer is poor: The click-to-call plug-in still modifies your DOM by inserting spans, which can have side effects on your CSS and $() selectors. Also the click to call functionality will still work (which we definitely don't want in our situation, because it is detecting cost-center codes as phone numbers - arrgh). Also using CSS is fragile - your fix will break if they change the plug-in in future.

Comment: This didn't help with Opera Mobile, which makes some numbers blue and clickable, e.g. `123.45`.

Answer (score 20):

Add this

```
<meta name="SKYPE_TOOLBAR" content ="SKYPE_TOOLBAR_PARSER_COMPATIBLE"/>
```

Comment: Only this works properly. Further explanation http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/34862/what-is-the-skype-toolbar-meta

Comment: I just tested that using `<meta name="SKYPE_TOOLBAR" content="SKYPE_TOOLBAR_PARSER_COMPATIBLE">` still disables the Skype click-to-call phone number highlighting. I installed Skype Click To Call and enabled the plug-in in IE11. A test webpage with phone numbers in it and without the meta tag, now has the phone number elements modified (e.g. a parent span is inserted with `onclick="SkypeClick2Call.MenuInjectionHandler.makeCall(this, event)"`). I added the meta tag into my page head, and the phone numbers are no longer modified (neither was the window.SkypeClick2Call object injected any more).

Comment: This didn't help with Opera Mobile, which makes some numbers blue and clickable, e.g. `123.45`.

Answer (score 5):

After searching Google for an answer to this, it seems the issue still persists as we approach the year 2012. Apparently the `<meta>` tag no longer works, and the Skype plugin is as intrusive as ever - *ruining SKU and part numbers* in some instances (incorrectly interpreting them as phone numbers).

I was surprised to see so many people misunderstand the desire to disable this from a web developer's point of view, and offer solutions to turn it off by changing browser settings and the like. Of course, we can't really expect our users to do this.

Skype will take something like this:

```
555-555-5555
```

And turn it into this:

```
<span class="skype_pnh_print_container">
    555-555-5555
</span>
<span class="skype_pnh_container" dir="ltr">
    <span class="skype_pnh_mark"> begin_of_the_skype_highlighting</span> 
        <span class="skype_pnh_highlighting_inactive_common" title="Call this phone number in United States of America with Skype: +15555555555" dir="ltr">
            <span class="skype_pnh_textarea_span"><span class="skype_pnh_text_span">555-555-5555</span>
            </span>
        </span>
    <span class="skype_pnh_mark">end_of_the_skype_highlighting</span>
</span>
```

Which looks like this: [image: Skype clickable phone number]

Copy and pasting a Skype'd phone number in rich text (like in an email, WYSIWYG or Word document) may end up something like this:

```
begin_of_the_skype_highlighting 555-555-5555 end_of_the_skype_highlighting
```

Awful, and there's no definitive way to prevent it. The [only way I found](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/751.cfm) to deal with this intrusion is by removing the markup with javascript.

Example using jQuery:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {

    // Remove the class from the wrapper <span> Skype adds to the number
    $('.skype_pnh_print_container').removeClass('skype_pnh_print_container');

    // Remove the generated content from Skype
    $('.skype_pnh_container').remove();

}, 100); // If it doesn't work, set a higher value
```

You will get a flash of ugliness first, but the `setTimeout` is necessary because the Skype content is generated just after the page is loaded.

Comment: +1 for really addressing the question. Shame the solution is so ugly.

Comment: Some of the newer clients have changed the class name. In addition to the excellent answer above you will want to add: 
 $('.skype_c2c_print_container').removeClass('skype_c2c_print_container');
$('.skype_c2c_container').remove();

To your script.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the (updated) css as suggested by hans, but it doesn't work in the latest version of Chrome (17.0.963.78 m)

It seems the skype plugin has changed again as the code generated by skype (in my version of Chrome) is  different from that shown by Madmartigan

I tried putting a comment in the middle of my phone number:

eg:

```
555<!--stop skype -->-555-5555
```

And this seems to work. i.e it stops skype recognising it as a phone number.
The only thing I'm not sure of is how it affects a Google search for the phone number.

I did run the page through a bot simulator:

http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/se-bot-simulator.html

and the comment didn't show up, so I'm hoping it won't affect Google search.

CSS would be the best solution for me but is too much of a moving target, so I prefer the 'comment' approach to the javascript one, but I guess different approaches are easier in different cases.

**edit**

OK eat my words.
Skype is quite smart. If your phone number is prefixed by the words "call us on" rather than "phone" which I initially tested with, then adding a comment inside the number doesn't work.

I tried another approach which is to use the soft hyphen e.g.

```
555&shy;-555-5555
```

and this worked.

Comment: This does work, the only problem with this approach is it will stop phone numbers from being detected on mobile phones as well. So unfortunately web developers are being held hostage by some idiot programmer at Skype/Microsoft who had the moronic idea to alter the html on a page with the ugly monstrosity that is their clickable numbers. Morons.

Comment: you can wrap your phone number in a "tel:" command to make it clickable on mobile phones e.g.

     <a href="tel:5555555555">555&shy; 555-5555</a>

Answer (score 1):

That is the skype plugin of your browser. When you install skype software, it automatically adds that plugin for firefox and IE AFAIK.

Just remove the plugin or the software and you are good to go. Anyway, the visitors of your website may have the software installed though.

Comment: Yep, I do this too - hate that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any PHP or JavaScript code that can remove Skype icons from phone numbers:
But there are several ways that you can stop Skype from highlighting (i.e. remove skype icon) phone numbers:

From a Developers point of View you can:

1. Use HTML: Soft Hyphen
2. Use CSS
3. Or use Meta Tag

From a user's point of view, the user can:

1. Disable or uninstall skype add-on from the browser. (see [comment](http://bacsoftwareconsulting.com/blog/index.php/web-development/prevent-skype-from-highlighting-phone-numbers/comment-page-2/#comment-8084))

For more details check the reference: [How To Prevent Skype from Highlighting Phone Numbers](http://bacsoftwareconsulting.com/blog/index.php/web-development/prevent-skype-from-highlighting-phone-numbers/)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst a link may theoretically answer the question, you should [include the essential parts of the answer here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259), and provide the link for reference (like you did after the edit). Your original answer just had a link, that's why it was deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Skype and see if it changes.

Skype usually interacts witht your browser and adds its own formatting for phone numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps have to implement into code.

Step 1:
add meta tag and style into your page head

`<head>`

**`<meta name="SKYPE_TOOLBAR" content ="SKYPE_TOOLBAR_PARSER_COMPATIBLE"/>`**

`<style>`

**`span.skype_pnh_container {display:none !important;}`
`span.skype_pnh_print_container {display:inline !important;}`**

`</style>`

`</head>`

Step 2:
wrap your numbers inside `<span>` like:

**`<span>123-</span><span>123-1234</span>`**

This worked for me. :)

Answer (score -3):

> on browser phone number are showing with skype icon

No they are not. Some browsers may have specific functionality for this. Alternatively it may be implemented by the site serving the page. In the case of the former, you'd need to provide detils of which browser - and its probably not controllable from serverside anyway.

C.

Answer (score -3):

No need for anything complicated, just go to *your browser -> internet options -> Programs -> Manage add-ons*, find Skype, click on *to call*, and then disable it.

That's it!

Comment: This is StackOverflow, a programming site. The question is asked from the perspective of someone writing a website, not running a browser.

Comment: So you expect every interweb user to deal with this before loading your site? Wow.